# Center text inside this element/override deadspace?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, centering

I'm not sure what the problem is here, but inside of this element there's some deadspace off to the left that doesn't respond to anything I do.  I want to center the text inside the element (and it *is* centered, only there's some void space to the left that doesn't seem to be taken into account). Here's a picture:

[image]

You can see how the padding on the left is much greater than the padding on the right.  I tried to manually set `padding-left` but that didn't work.

here's the element in the page (i'm using rails):

```
<div class="holder round clear eval_body">
  ...
  <div class="box center">
    Before continuing to the next student, 
    <br />please take a moment to review the scores for <%= @student.name %>.
    <br />  
    <span class='strong'>
      Once you have submitted them, they cannot be changed!
    </span>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

and the `box` element

```
.box {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 3px;
    left: 10em;
    width: 50%;
    height: 8%;
    background: #B05C37;
    border: 3px solid #902D00;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Either the position should be absolute or left & bottom should be margin-left and margin-bottom.

Comment: It looks fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/3HdKJ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the suggestions (especially [techvineet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1460496/techvineet)).  Got it working with this:

```
.box {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 3.5%;
    right: 7%;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    background: #B05C37;
    border: 3px solid #902D00;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your css class to `.box center` instead of `.box`

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
text-align: center;
```

to your .box in CSS.